# electron - process.env.NODE_ENV is always 'development' even in production

Tags: build, environment-variables, electron-builder

I'm trying to build my electron app with electron-builder, the running command is "yarn run build".
The process.env.NODE_ENV value is always 'development' even in production.
I tried to set in package.json, under scripts the prefix NODE_ENV=production before the build command, the actual value is still 'development' instead of 'production'.
How can I fix the NODE_ENV variable to be correct depends on its environment?
thanks a lot.

the package.json attached below.

```
  {
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:mac": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder",
    "build:dir": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder --dir",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "NODE_ENV=production cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "ELECTRON_ENV=development node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "staging": "ELECTRON_ENV=staging node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "win-dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "e2e": "npm run pack && mocha test/e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter src test",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter --fix src test",
    "pack": "npm run pack:main && npm run pack:renderer",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "unit": "karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production electron-builder --mac --win --publish always",
    "deploy-mac": "NODE_ENV=production electron-builder --mac --publish always",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production electron-builder build --mac --publish never",
    "postinstall": "npm run lint:fix"
  },
  "build": {
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "afterSign": "build/scripts/notarize.js",
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ],
      "sign": false
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "dmg",
        "zip"
      ],
      "icon": "static/icons/icon.icns",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "static/icons/icon.ico"
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "static/icons/icon.png"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/electron": "1.0.0",
    "auto-launch": "^5.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "axios-response-logger": "^0.1.0",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^0.2.0",
    "csv-parser": "^2.3.1",
    "dropbox": "^4.0.30",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.1",
    "electron-notarize": "^0.2.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6",
    "electron-transparency-mouse-fix": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "electron-window-state": "^5.0.3",
    "filestack-js": "^3.7.0",
    "firebase": "^7.1.0",
    "geometric": "^2.2.0",
    "kalmanjs": "^1.1.0",
    "rollup": "^1.15.6",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.4.20",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-electron": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "cfonts": "^2.1.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "6.0.10",
    "electron-builder": "^22.2.0",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.5",
    "electron-updater": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "inject-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-electron": "^6.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "multispinner": "^0.2.1",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "require-dir": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "spectron": "^3.8.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value a the top of `.electron-vue/build.js` file. It's the file that gets called on build.

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```